# Problem with OR in composite index

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

In many of my queries i have scenario like

```
SELECT * from myTable m 
where m.userId = :userId
AND  (m.to = :contactNumber OR m.from = :contactNumber)
AND .....
```

So i made a composite index for (userId, to, from)

It works fine if `OR` is replaced by `AND`, but in case of `OR` it just uses the index for `userId`.

I'm little confused why this is happening, also is there any better way to index this to increase performance, may be index all of them individually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A composite index searches for a couple of things lumped together. It might help to look at it as being an index of the various columns concatenated.

So if you use or, you are looking for a combination of userid and to, OR userid and from. But not all 3 together!

It is a bit depending on the contents and all, but you could add 2 composites for the boths "sub" queries (so userid and to + userid and from). But isn't the userid index enough? If that will take down your rows enough for it to be managable, I wouldn't go and add all sorts of composite indexes...

Answer (score 2):

You just need to think about how the composite index is put together. The keys will be sorted primarily on `userId`. Within each `userId`, they'll be sorted by `to` and, within each one of *those* groups, it will be sorted by `from`.

That means that, while you could use that index to find specific `userId` values, `userId:to` pairs and `userId:to:from` triplets, it's not much good for finding specific `userId:from` pairs. That's because those values will be at many different places in the index order, since `to` is a higher-level key than `from`.

One way to do this would be to put an extra index on `userId:from` and then use two *separate* queries in a union, both of which can use their own index to efficiently find the rows. Something like:

```
select * from myTable m
    where m.userId = :userId and m.to = :contactNumber
union
select * from myTable m
    where m.userId = :userId and m.from = :contactNumber
```

The first query of that will most likely use your original index since `userId:to` is its two top-level components. You *could* also have an index on just that but it's probably not necessary since you already have a usable index (and that may be used for your other queries where you want rows with all three components).

The second query will probably use the new index to efficiently find its rows.

The `union` will them combine the two queries and remove the duplicates. This is needed to match the intent of the original query. If you knew that there could be no crossover between the queries then you could use `union all` to skip the (unnecessary) duplicate removal step but I don't think you can do that here.

This method also has the potential advantage of being easily subject to parallelism in databases that support it (the queries could run side-by-side and be combined once both were finished).

Now keep in mind this is *general* advice. I'm a DB2 man myself so what I put forward here is based on general knowledge about how databases work internally, not specifics about MySQL.

You should still test the queries to ensure they act as expected (but I would think you would want to do that even if I was the *author* of MySQL). In other words, and I've lost count how many times I've said this here, *measure, don't guess!*

Comment: +1 for the **union** approach, actually i found that i'm not doing any good by keeping 3 indexes so i made them two(userId, from) as only these were used in many other queries